# Google compute Engine "Click to Deploy" allows only one cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using "Click to Deploy" to create 3-node cassandra cluster in my project.
No I need to create one more cluster for another purpose in the same project.
I am not able to create new one, as its showing the cluster is already installed and only option is to delete the existing cluster.

Comment: This is a known limitation we are working to fix.  In the meantime, a workaround is to create another project.

Comment: @chrispomeroy , Thanks for the reply.
Can you please post this in the answer section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation with the current version of Click to Deploy.  We are working on an update that will allow multiple deployments in a single project.  To @chrispomeroy's point, a current workaround is to create another project and deploy your next cluster.