# Multiple deployment on same GCE cluster

Tags: deployment, google-compute-engine

I have created a 3 node cluster with Hadoop and Spark on GCE through one click deploy.
How can I deploy anything else on the same cluster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google compute Engine "Click to Deploy" allows only one cassandra cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509438/google-compute-engine-click-to-deploy-allows-only-one-cassandra-cluster)

Comment: My requirement is just the opposite. I want to make another deployment on the same cluster(already deployed with hadoop).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "deploy" then? You're not trying to deploy another (separate) Hadoop cluster? Are you trying to add nodes to the cluster, or deploy some other infrastructure into the same cluster? Please revise your question to add more details.

Comment: GCE console lets me create a seperate cassandra cluster. I want to install  cassandra on the hadoop cluster, that is already deployed. How to do this?

Comment: Just SSH to any of the nodes in the cluster either via the web browser by using the "SSH" button next to a VM instance or use [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) and follow the standard installation procedure for Cassandra from their docs.

Comment: I have done the same, but wondering if the one click deployment can be done on the hadoop cluster.

Comment: I don't think Click to Deploy can deploy on existing Hadoop clusters; I believe it only provisions new VMs and installs software on them.